# heroku explain environments/production.rb

Tags: heroku, asset-pipeline, staging

I have a staging environment for my application. I wanted to enable assets precompilation, but there was no clear way for me to do this. I ended up copying over many lines in my `environments/production.rb` file to `environments/staging.rb`

## current staging.rb

```
Dezzmo0003::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # my settings to get assets compiled on staging
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :info
  config.assets.precompile += %w( landing.js pages.js users.js )
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
end
```

my question is. Where can I look up all these features and understand what they do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to look up the majority of the config settings for a Rails app is the [official Rails configuration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).  They give most of the available config settings in that document and what they do.

If there's one that you don't find in that doc but is in your config file, I'd suggest just Googling the configuration variable (e.g. Google: `config.assets.debug`) and see what people say about it.